# How can I add specific numbers of each classification that my NN can predict?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, classification, lstm, multilabel-classification

I have an np-array something like one-hot-encoding with 0-1. For each sample I always have 15 zeros and 5 ones. What can I do to make it predict 5 ones and 15 zeros only? I am using the keras library is there a setting I can apply so that my model have to predict exactly 15 zeros and 5 ones?

-

example of input = [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]

```
#Building RNN
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout

regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],20)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(Dense(units = 20, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compiling RNN
regressor.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I would like my model always predicting 15 zeros and 5 ones.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try to define your custom loss function which returns according your format

```py
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

  # calculate binary_crossentropy and reshape the result according your need
  ...

  return K.variable(...)
```

```py
regressor.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with rigorous training.  Heavily penalize anything that has any other distribution. Experiment with heavier penalties for the difference between the prediction and exactly 5 `1`s.

You can do most or all of this by writing an appropriate loss function.